# C# DataGridView is not showing data

Tags: c#, database, winforms, ms-access, datagridview

I am having issues displaying data from an access database to my datagridview. There are two rows in the database I am hitting. What am I missing?

```
string strProvider = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data   Source=C:\Database\mydatabase.accdb;Persist Security Info=True";
    string strSql = "Select * from mytable";
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(strProvider);
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(strSql, con);
    con.Open();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable scores = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(scores);
    data_grid_main.DataSource = scores;
```

Comment: Exactly what issues are you having?

Answer (score 0):

data_grid_main.databind() is missing I  guess. Try adding that.